# Highcharts support for weighted edge

Tags: highcharts

Does Highcharts support weighted edges between two nodes? No the global settings for all links but to configure each individual link LENGTH based on weight so that the links indicate closeness between nodes.

For example:

[HighCharts network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IebY.png)

Is HighCharts capable of configuring the lengths of links between 0,1 and 2 based on their corresponding weights?

Comment: More details more details.

Comment: What specific series do you have in mind? Is it the network graph?